# How to DRY frontend/backend constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a constant `ANIMALS = %w(dog cat horse)`.
What is an ideal way to provide it to frontend scripts to avoid duplicating it there?
One way of doing it is assigning it to a global from a view, kind of like this:

```
<script>
  Constants.animals = <%=raw ANIMALS %>
</script>
```

but is there a way of doing it better?

Comment: @Зелёный I'm not sure if you understand question correctly. The question is, how to avoid duplication between Ruby code (server side) and JS code (client side), because OP wants to use this in both sides.

Comment: @MarekLipka thx, i should more learn english instead ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I always put my constants within the model that it belongs to. This is how I would do something like this:

```
class Animal
    ANIMAL_TYPES = ['dog', 'cat', 'horse']
end
```

Now I can use this constant anywhere including like this

```
<script>
    Constants.animals = <%=raw Animal::ANIMAL_TYPES %>
</script>
```

Comment: I think you got the question wrong. The OP has asked a way to avoid the script altogether and have a ruby constant available in JS somehow.